# jenkins jira integration using ZAPI and zephyr

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-zephyr

i have installed Zephyr plugin in jenkins and ZAPI,Zephyr plugin in jira and able to establish the connection as well

but in drop down am not able view the jira project

can anyone help me to resolve this issue[in post build not able to view the project name in drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mkhr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to complete the global configuration for Zephyr in Jenkins.

Should be somewhere in *Manage Jenkins* --> *Configure System* --> search for *Zephyr* here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the plugin a little non-intuitive. Even if you have configured the global configuration section, upon adding the the Zephyr component to a job for the first time, you must save the job. When you edit the job you'll be able to select the project, cycle etc.